# I got different cost prices for the same item on different batch Formula for batch cost price in sales

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I been stuck with this formula for the past week just to get the proper cost price for my "Sales".

Condition:

1. In "Purchases" got different cost price for every batch I get

Question:

2. How to fix the formula to get the cost in "Sales" accordingly?
   Example:

---

```
Purchases:
Pen101 - Cost Price: $1 - Quantity: 10
Pen102 - Cost Price: $1.20 - Quantity: 10
Pen103 - Cost Price: $1.10 - Quantity: 10

Sales:
Order 1 - Pen - Quantity 5 = Cost $1 x 5 = $5
Order 2 - Pen - Quantity 10 = Cost ($1x5)+($1.20*5)= $11
```

The formula I need is for the proper formula for cost price, cause I'm using Vlookup and it will just showing me $1 for the cost only. I remark the correct cost price I did put the correct cost price that it should get at the side for reference.

Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19-mLagjPNgG3eFkFVG0ip8R5K95NwSZ5YmBxCOgzYmY/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: In Column Cost Price I need the formula. Cause it's not showing the correct cost price as for now.

Comment: I had created the solution in Sheet12, try to enter a value in `F11` in sales tab to see the result in `I5` Sheet12 tab. (If you are ok with it I'll put it as an answer, if need more tweaking/understanding on how it work/setup.. u r welcomed to ask)